# node.js RESTful API with amazon like auth

Tags: rest, node.js, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I'm looking to build a RESTful API in node.js and want to authenticate users with an API key and API secret musch like the service in Amazon Web Services (AWS).

The question is where to start, googling has lead me to a lot of irrelevant sites and I wondered if anyone had some good site suggestions of sample or skeleton code?

Thanks Ric

Comment: You should take a look at OAuth which is rapidly becoming the standard for authenticating APIs. http://search.npmjs.org - search for oauth there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an oAuth2 provider module. oAuth is quickly becoming the standard for API's.

https://github.com/AF83/oauth2_server_node